# positive semidefinite operator and isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f$ be an aribitrary linear isomorphism of euclidean space V . Prove there exists $r_1, r_2$ - positive semidefinite operators (self adjoint opertors such that $\langle f(a),a \rangle \ge 0$ for every a) and $g_1, g_2$ - isometries such that $f=r_1 \circ g_1$ and $f=g_2 \circ r_2$ and show $r_1, r_2, g_1, g_2$ are uniquely determined

I'd be grateful for any help since I don't know how to tackle this

Comment: What do you mean by *"linear isomorphism of subspace $V$?"*

Comment: It seems as though you're looking for a proof that every matrix has a [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition)

Comment: Did you mean *"a finite dimensional space $V$"*?

Comment: yes it looks like polar decomposition with addition that it's isomorphism , does it simplify proof ? by isomorphism I mean it's invertible or transform basis to basis

Comment: What do you mean by "subspace"? Do you just mean that $V$ is a vector space?

Comment: sorry it's just euclidan space

Comment: Do you know about singular value decomposition?

Comment: yes, I know what it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick proof using singular value decomposition:

We note that $f$ has an SVD.  That is, there are isometries $g,h$ such that
$$
f = g \circ \sigma \circ h
$$
where $h$ is the map 
$$
\sigma(x_1,\dots,x_n) = (\sigma_1 x_1, \dots, \sigma_n x_n)
$$
with $\sigma_j \geq 0$. $\sigma$ is positive semidefinite. We may then write
$$
f = (g \circ h) \circ (h^{-1} \circ \sigma \circ h)
$$
Define $g_2 = g \circ h$ and $r_2 = h^{-1} \circ \sigma \circ h$.  We have $f = g_2 \circ r_2$, as desired.

Now, note that $r_2 = \sqrt{f^* \circ f}$, which is uniquely determined.  $f$ is invertible, so $r_2$ is invertible.  We then have $g_2 = f \circ r_2^{-1}$.  So, both $r_2$ and $g_2$ are uniquely determined.

The other proof is similar.

Comment: why $h^{-1}\sigma h$  is self adjoint positive operator ?

Comment: Because $h^{-1} = h^*$

Comment: how to obtain $r_2=\sqrt{f^*f}$ ?

Comment: $$f^*f = (g_2 r_2 )^*(g_2 r_2)= r_2^* g_2^* g_2 r_2 = r_2^2$$